# Switch debouncing

Tags: filter, debouncing

I  am trying to implement a push button in my design.  The catch is that button must be quite far from the main board (about 1 m.) I  implemented a simple key debouncing filter from the internet:

[image]

It didn't really help. I then  tried adding one 10 uF capacitor in parallel to the 100  nF, then two but I still get quite a lot of vibrations, which are being registered by my interrupt handler. Any ideas why these filters are not working?

Logic analyzer capture:

[image]

I don't want to implement any software debouncing because I am very strict on timing and afraid that this will bring delays and latency to my algorithm. Any ideas how to bypass this problem?

Comment: You will get this problem whether the distance is far or near. Disable interrupts as soon as the first pulse arrives. Re-enable interrupts after (say) 20 ms. Your image has no scale and nothing meaningful is presented by it.

Comment: "afraid, that this will bring delays and latency to my algorithm." A button is incredibly slow compared to software running on a microcontroller (which is exactly why you need debouncing". So, your fear seems fully unfounded. It's even inherenty **counter-productive**! Your analog filter inherently adds latency, that's literally its purpose. Software debounce would not. So, maybe more *engineering*, less hearsay?

Answer (score 4):

10µF with 1k make the time constant 10ms. The low quality buttons bounce about 10ms. There is also a high chance the bounce occurs right at Vcc/2 (when logic flips) so you will never debounce 100% correctly. You can reach close to 100%  with an RC filter (like 1k*22µF) and a Schmitt trigger.

I think this RC filter is a little better:

[image]

The capacitor voltage falls to 0V, not 1/10 of Vcc like yours.

Comment: This is the solution. However I'd use 10K or 22K for the pull up resistor and 1 to 10uF for the cap. It may even work without the schmitt trigger but it's much better with. A resistor instead the schmitt trigger may also help.

Comment: @Fredled I would argue against larger resistances, because the long wires will induce noise current. I would want to keep currents as *high* as possible.

Comment: @SimonFitch The larger the resistance, the lower the bouncing and off voltage range spikes. Current doesn't have to be "high". Voltage have to. Voltage can be high with large resistance.

Answer (score 2):

With microprocessors, debouncing is almost always a function of software, not hardware. Once the GPIO interrupt triggers on the button press, disable the interrupt source from that GPIO pin and schedule a timer that will call a function that re-enables the GPIO. How exactly that would be done depends on the MCU and software architecture.

If you have some sort of a global timer tick and that can be used for the purpose. The global timer tick may handle a list of timeouts that are queued from various places in the firmware. Or it may be a simple custom ISR that handles the few specific timeouts directly as needed, based on some global flags. Those are just two out of many potential approaches to that.

> I don't want to implement any software debouncing because I am very strict on timing and afraid that this will bring delays and latency to my algorithm.

I have bad news then: you are not strict on timing at all. To be strict on timing you need to have a way to measure it: a way that’s readily accessible and can be a part of automated software testing. So that you know that changes to code won’t break it timing-wise.

If you were strict and per implication had test results, hard numbers to look at, available at will, you would not be afraid because you could tell whether the timing is with it acceptable bounds or not.

Instead, it looks to me like you’re acting on some vague intuition that’s not backed by data. This will unduly constrain your development process since you’ll forever remain afraid of change, and use this “but what about the timing” argument. If you can’t measure it, readily and efficiently as part of the development process, you’re not serious about it.

Good news, though: software debouncing on most architectures takes a couple dozen machine instructions per input, and it has a fixed maximum cost per second, independent of the number of input transitions. When implemented correctly that is. Perhaps you have some less efficient implementation in mind that does not have such fixed and very small upper bound in the number of instructions needed.

Comment: This "trigger on first edge then ignore for a bit" method has worked very well for me in practice.  Your delay is minimal because you're triggering on the first edge (unlike an RC circuit), tuning to your switch is as easy (or hard) as suppressing the examination of the input for a known period of time, it doesn't take many lines of code (if your framework is sane) and it doesn't contribute much to processor loading (again, if your framework is sane).

Comment: One pedantic note that I drop on every newbie to switch debounce: every switch has it's own length of time that it wants to bounce, and not only does it vary from brand to brand and switch to switch, but also with age.  So measure how long it takes for your switch to settle, then multiply by 10 or 20 -- and if that's too long, consider a different switch or a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

The RC filter causes the voltage seen by MCU to rise and fall slowly, and slowly changing signals should never be directly used for triggering interrupts.

So this is basically itself a wrong solution and RC filter makes the problem worse. And it will anyway add the delay of RC charging time, if you need to react to the button fast.

Most MCU inputs do not implement enough hysteresis to drive interrupt inputs with slow RC filtered signals.

Either trigger on the first edge, or add more hysteresis, by using a Schmitt trigger to square up the slowly changing signal to sharp edges for the MCU.